# Troubleshooting Unresolved External Symbol Error during Python Extension Module Compilation

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, error-handling, cython

I'm trying to run this project
https://github.com/CMU-SAFARI/Sibyl
I followed the steps mentioned in github repo. After running the command `python setup.py develop` on my command prompt, it popped out this error.
I'm using cython 0.29.21
Any help solving this issue is much appreciated.

```
 Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\pandas\_libs\internals.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\pandas\_libs\internals.cp310-win_amd64.exp
internals.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyGen_Send
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas\_libs\internals.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
```

I tried using various versions of libraries of TensorFlow, and pandas. I've installed Visual Studio C++ tools 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update Cython. The function was removed from Python. Cython 0.29.22 was the first version to adapt to the change: https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/b37607f46b165e81f7af2b4eec2ae7f76f7717df.